# How can the tags in cucumber hooks(@Before and @After) be organised

Tags: node.js, cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

I have two step definitions that contain two types of tags (populate and test)

1. First step def - cars.ts that contains the following tags: @populate_cars1, @cars1, @populate_cars2, @cars2.
2. Second step def - clients.ts contains the following tags: @populate_clients1, @clients1, @populate_clients2, @clients2.

In hooks I have the following definition:

-> Before("not @populate_cars1 and not @populate_cars2 and not @populate_clients1 and not @populate_clients2", function(){...}) - works as expected

-> After("not @cars1 and not @cars2 and not @clients1 and not @clients2", function(){...}) - works as expected.

I want to organised the tags like below:
`let pop_car = "not @populate_cars1 and not @populate_cars2"`
`let pop_client = "and not @populate_clients1 and not @populate_clients2"`
`@Before(pop_car + pop_client, function(){...})`

I have for each step def a variable that contains operations between tags and concatenate the variable to get a string.

The issue is when I concatenate the variable "pop_car + pop_client" - the hook **@Before is called**.

Comment: Can you add an example where you concatenate the variables? And the terminal log showing the @Before being called, if possible?

Comment: the variables were concatenate in @Before, like above. Also, I tried to concatenate variable before call @Before and added the string in@Before.                                     `let pop_car = "not @populate_cars1 and not @populate_cars2"
let pop_client = "and not @populate_clients1 and not @populate_clients2"

Before("pop_car+pop_client", function () {
console.log("init db before test")
return populateDB('development', true)
})` in the trace I saw the console log before each test.

Comment: I don't quite understand what is the issue? You are calling @Before and the hook is called. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Yes. If I put  'Before("not @populate_cars1 and not @populate_cars2 and not @populate_clients1 and not @populate_clients2", function(){...})' - it works as expected. In this case @Before has 4 tags from feature Car and Clients. I want to have @Before(_before),  _before = tagsCar + tagsClient. In this case `@Before`  didn't works as expected. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try with `Before("pop_car" + " " + "pop_client")`. (added a space between them)

Comment: I don't want to initialized db before each test, because in the first test I populate db and the second is the test itself.

Comment: Maybe you could look into "BeforeAll" hook that could populate the DB?

Comment: Thank you! now it works!!  I forgot to concatenate with space between variables " ".

Comment: I added this as an answer. You can upvote and/or accept it if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space between the concatenated variables.

Try with:

```
@Before("pop_car" + " " + "pop_client")
```